# Routing to AWS ElastickBeanstalk vs. Load Balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

What is the best practice to forward workload from AWS Route53? Should I send it to the ElasticBeanstalk environment or to the LoadBalancer assigned to that EB? What are the pros and cons of each method?

P.S. REST API, PHP

Comment: Do you have load balancer in your EB or not?

Comment: Yes, there is a Load Balancer assigned to my EB environment

Comment: Hi, mate. Yes, it's still unclear what I should do. Which way to choose. See my comment under your answer, please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have ALB in-front of your EB, you should setup alias record in R53 **to the EB's url**. It will resolve to ALB's address anyway.

The biggest benefit of doing that is that EB's url gets automatically updated to new EB environment, if you are doing [blue/green deployments](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.CNAMESwap.html). This way you don't have to worry about validity of your R53 alias record, as it will always point to the correct ALB.

In contrast, if you link R53 to ALB directly, you use the above benefit.

Also, but not fully sure about that, using EB's URL ensure that R53 will use your EB environment health status. If you just use ALB url in R53, any extra health checks that EB provides will not be account for in R53.

Comment: We don't use blue/green deployments. We use Rolling updates(min 2 EC2 instances). I also didn't fully get your point about health check for R53. Would you explain it, please? Regardless updating, are there other benefits/downsides of having an R53 alias pointing to ALB? BTW, it's a Shared ALB created independently from EB. Thanks

Comment: @Kostiantyn R53 can [automatically monitor health](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/dns-failover.html) of your application. The checks will be based on ALB if you just use ALB, or EB. EB's health checks are [much more comprehensive](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/environments-health.html) then ALBs.

Comment: Thanks for that. Good to know. Are you saying that apart from health check and deployments there are no differences in which way yo use: R53->EB or R53->ALB?

Comment: @Kostiantyn Yes, I'm not aware of other differences.

Comment: Thank you. It gives me much more confidence.